# I need to know how to create a dropdown menu using ONLY Javascript, no other programming language involved

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dropdown

Basically, I have a simple and program and want to know how to create a dropdown menu WITHIN a function, using only Javascript, no HTML or any other language involved. Kind of similar to things like document.write.
This is a short snippet of my code; this is within a function and written in Javascript:

I haven't found any solution to this problem and so have not tried anything.

```
var menu = document.getElementById("num_of_teams");
menu.addEventListener("change", generateData);

function generateData(event) {
    var lb = "<br\>";
    if (menu.value == '2') {
       alert("You have selected 2 teams. Would you like to proceed?");
       let first_team = prompt("What is the name of your first team?");
       let second_team = prompt("What is the name of your second team?");
       document.write("GAMES PLAYED:");   
       document.write(lb);
       document.write (first_team+"(H) vs."+second_team+"(A)");          
       document.write(lb);
       document.write (second_team+"(H) vs."+first_team+"(A)");
  }
```

I would expect for a dropdown with options that I have assigned to be displayed on-screen. I would also want to be able to call a function onClick().

Comment: "...using only Javascript, no HTML..." That's not possible. JS doesn't have presentational logic. In other words, JS can't display anything (except browser-based modals like alert/prompt/etc., but even those are considered obsolete and should be avoided). Anything displayed on screen will use HTML. Think of HTML as the language you use to display stuff, and JS as the language you use to change the behavior of the stuff that's displayed. JS is behavior/control logic, HTML is display.

Comment: Sound like homework, what have you tried yourself? What is your html structure?

Comment: do not use document.write

Answer (score 0):

You can create a full html page not just a dropdown list by Pure Javascript but it's necessary to define the script on an html page in the minimum you can define a simple html page like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And complete your work using javascript like that for example i will add a simple dropDown list using `<select></select>` tag

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
for (var i=0; i < 4; i += 1) {
 var option = document.createElement("option"),
     text = document.createTextNode("option" + i);
 option.appendChild(text);
 select.appendChild(option);
}
document.body.appendChild(select);
```