# Drop down menu in GoogleSheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Can someone provide insight on how to create a drop down menu in cell (lets say) A1 in Googlesheets with three values(or more) that are taken from an array using Javascript?

I know it is easier to do it through Googlesheets but i just want to learn the javascript code to create drop down menus.

Comment: Have you read [I need to know how to create a dropdown menu using ONLY Javascript, no other programming language involved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57118602/1330560)

Comment: Yes but that does not correspond to googlesheets and does not make any sense to me. I mean I do not understand how I can use that code for googlesheets.

Comment: I suspect that you can use datavalidation anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Refer to the second of the two answers in [Create dynamic dropdown list in the Google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21266568/1330560)

Comment: If you want to achieve this using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), please refer to the second link provided by Tedinoz. If that's not the case, please clarify how you want to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
function dropDownBox() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
    var value =['Jack', 'Jim', 'Elena'];
    var dropdown = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
        .requireValueInList(value)
        .build();
    sheet.setDataValidation(dropdown)
}
```